# prevent page break a couple of lines after figure

Tags: floats, page-breaking

I am writing a document which consists of the repeating format: text, figure, then a larger paragraph. How can I prevent a page break *between* both of the text and `figure` environments, whilst not removing the ability to automatically break the page *within* the body of the second text?

`\nopagebreak` doesn't seem to have any effect after the `figure` environment. (And I assume confining it to a `minipage` would not allow page-breaking in this second paragraph.)

I'm fine with white space at the end of a page, but I'd rather each repeating group not necessarily start on a new page.

Comment: This is a big classical question. 1) see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229299/how-to-keep-tables-closer and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned 2) try `\begin{figure}[htp]` 3) try `float` package and `\begin{figure}[H]` 4) try with`caption` package don't float the figure.

Answer (score 1):

May be that what the OP is looking for is simply a version of, say, the `center` environment which prohibits page breaks above and below itself; this is easy to accomplish.  For example, the following MWE defines an environment named `centernopagebreaks` that locally redefines the appropriate parameters and then invokes the `center` environment.

**Note:** While testing this example, I’ve noticed that the `\captionof` command inserts a legal breakpoint *between* the figure and its caption.  I’ve made up for this by wrapping everything up in a `minipage` environment, but isn’t this a bug?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mwe}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment*{centernopagebreaks}{%
  \@beginparpenalty \@M
  \@endparpenalty   \@M
  \@itempenalty     \@M
  \center
}{\endcenter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{centernopagebreaks}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{image}
        \par\special{comment: Why no penalty below write and rule?}
        \captionof{figure}{An image}
        \label{fig;img}
    \end{minipage}
\end{centernopagebreaks}
\lipsum[1]

% % If you can read the logging info provided by (core) TeX,
% % uncomment the following lines to check the penalties.
% \showboxbreadth = 1000
% \showboxdepth = 5
% \showlists
\end{document}
```

I don’t think that it is meaningful to show the output; rather, you should uncomment the diagnostic commands and check that the penalties reported in the transcript file are correct.